# How to use NOW() with DatabaseDriver->insertObject()

Tags: joomla-4.x, mysql

I'm inserting an object in a database table using joomla 4, as per [joomla docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase#Using_an_Object):

```
$toInsert = new stdClass();
$toInsert->update_timestamp = 'NOW()';
$toInsert->id = null;

$db = Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
$db->insertObject('table', $toInsert, 'id');
```

However, that results in

> Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()' for column 'update_timestamp' at row
> 1

How do I use NOW() using insertObject()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using arrays to compose the sql query, as per this alternative mentioned in the [joomla docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase#Using_SQL), which works fine:

```
$columns = array('update_timestamp');
$values = array('NOW()');
$db = Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 
$query->insert($db->quoteName('table'))
      ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
      ->values(implode(',', $values));
```

Comment: Since you are imploding a hardcoded, single-element array, you can just write `->values('NOW()')`

Comment: @Jimmy if this has resolved your original question please be sure to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to insert a row into the database [using an object](https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase#Using_an_Object), you are going to need to pass in values that do not leverage SQL functions.  `insertObject()` will treat the object's payload as literal values for security/stability.

Another bit of magic is that you must not try to declare a `null` value in your object's payload.  Instead, you should omit the property from the object entirely if you wish `NULL` to be added for a given database table column.

I don't see anywhere in the `insertObject()` method's argument signature to allow SQL keywords/functions to be rendered. Unless someone else knows better than me, this means you should use PHP's datetime capabilities to populate the current time.

That said, I think my best advice is to set the column's default value to the current datetime. This way you never need to mention the column when you build an insert object.

A "TRIGGER" can be helpful if you want update `update_timestamp` after every change made.

Maybe these will inspire:

- [MySQL insert with the current timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23540354/2943403)
- [How do you set a default value for a MySQL Datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/168736/2943403)
- [How to set default value of MySQL DateTime ( not TIMESTAMP ) to NOW() or Current_DateTIme?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6283821/2943403)